# Questions about creating an SQS queue/dead letter queue on AWS with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I want to create an SQS queue that is connected to a dead letter queue. I want messages that are received but can't be processed correctly from the SQS queue to be put on the dead letter queue. In addition I want to set this up doing cloud formation. I have looked at  [these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html#w2ab1c21c10d225c14c13). But I still have questions about the process of setting this up. I see this code snippet a bit of the ways down the page that shows how to do this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources: 
  MySourceQueue: 
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties: 
      RedrivePolicy: 
        deadLetterTargetArn: 
          Fn::GetAtt: 
            - "MyDeadLetterQueue"
            - "Arn"
        maxReceiveCount: 5
  MyDeadLetterQueue: 
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
Outputs: 
  SourceQueueURL: 
    Description: "URL of the source queue"
    Value: 
      Ref: "MySourceQueue"
  SourceQueueARN: 
    Description: "ARN of the source queue"
    Value: 
      Fn::GetAtt: 
        - "MySourceQueue"
        - "Arn"
  DeadLetterQueueURL: 
    Description: "URL of the dead letter queue"
    Value: 
      Ref: "MyDeadLetterQueue"
  DeadLetterQueueARN: 
    Description: "ARN of the dead letter queue"
    Value: 
      Fn::GetAtt: 
        - "MyDeadLetterQueue"
        - "Arn"
```

My questions are:

> 1) Is this code snippet for 1 sqs/dead letter queue? So If I want to
>   make many of these I would duplicate this entire block for each one?
>
> 2) If the sqs queue already exists but I want to add a dead letter
>   queue to it in cloud formation, can I just put the name of that queue 
>   somewhere and have it generate the correct dead letter queue? Or do I
>   have to tear down the old queues and re create them with cloud
>   formation?

Answer (score 7):

This snippet is creating an Amazon SQS queue called `MyDeadLetterQueue`:

```
  MyDeadLetterQueue: 
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
```

This snippet:

```
  MySourceQueue: 
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties: 
      RedrivePolicy: 
        deadLetterTargetArn: 
          Fn::GetAtt: 
            - "MyDeadLetterQueue"
            - "Arn"
        maxReceiveCount: 5
```

is saying:

- Create an Amazon SQS queue called `MySourceQueue`
- Set the Dead Letter Queue to `MyDeadLetterQueue`
- If a message fails to process 5 times, move it to `MyDeadLetterQueue`

Multiple queues can use the same Dead Letter Queue if you wish, so repeat this block for each queue you wish to create.

If the Dead Letter Queue already exists, then you can supply the ARN for the queue:

- Create a parameter to accept the ARN
- Refer to the ARN in the queue definition

For example:

```
Parameters: 
  DLQarn: 
    Type: String

Resources:
  MySourceQueue: 
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties: 
      RedrivePolicy: 
        deadLetterTargetArn: 
          Ref: DLQarn
        maxReceiveCount: 5
```